# Adding GTM tag on "Shopify > setting > checkout > additional script" isn't working.. How can I solve this?

Tags: shopify, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

Adding GTM tag on "Shopify > setting > checkout > additional script" isn't working.. How can I solve this?

- I tried placing Meta ad pixels in the same section and it also doesn't work...

I'm expecting the pixels placed on "additional scripts" to work, meaning on /checkouts page, the pixels should appear, but they dont. Now my pixels stopped working once I arrive the /checkouts page from homepage and product pages.

Comment: Are the tags present went you go into dev tools on that page ```ctrl+F```on the elements page? Could it be possible that the theme you are using does not support scripts on those pages?